# Why do some sets have two different numbers?

Tags: set-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did Lego use the same number for two different sets?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/302/why-did-lego-use-the-same-number-for-two-different-sets)

For example, [324 Ricky Racoon on his Scooter](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=324-1) and [3605 Ricky Racoon and his Scooter](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=3605-1) appear to be identical in every way but the set number. So why did Lego use two different numbers?

Comment: My first Technic set (and last LEGO set before the dark ages) was the 852 helicopter, which had number 954 in the US. http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/852_Helicopter

Comment: The two questions are different. This one is "one set, two numbers" while the other is "two sets, one number".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some cases, there were different numbers for the [USA](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=497-1) and the [rest of the world](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=928-1), but I don't know if that's the case with Ricky Racoon.

LEGO also extended from a 3-digit numbering to a 4-digit numbering around that time, so maybe some sets were renumbered. At the time, LEGO didn't seem to care that much about set numbers (and as [you've noted](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/302), reused some).

Comment: The Space sets also released first in North America in 1979 while Europe got Castle. The [Idea Book 6000](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6000-1) came out in 1980 depicting the full range to both sides.  In 1981 the distribution crossed over after Castle had test-marketed in a few cities in the US. The Castle sets like [383 Knights Tournament](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/383-2) got new 60xx numbers assigned at that time too.